# amsmath and amsfonts incompatibility issues

Tags: amsmath, incompatibility, amsfonts

In my code, I was using the `amsmath` package and some others and the command `\widehat` was working just fine, but when I added the package `amsfonts`, the output of `\widehat` started producing an error: the variable inside the command is duplicated in the output. For example, `\widehat{y}_{t_q}` produces:

[image]

If I remove the `amsfonts` package from the code, then the problem disappears. I would like to know how can I use both packages and avoid this error in the `\widehat` command. Thank you in advance for your attention and advice!

Erica

A short version of my code follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\bibpunct{(}{)}{,}{a}{,}{,}
\newcommand{\BibTeX}{{\sc Bib}\TeX}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}

\newenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\noindent\textbf{#1.} }{\ \rule{0.5em}{0.5em}}
\usepackage{a4wide}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{70}
\left( \begin{array}{c}
              v_{t_m} \\
              u_{t_m} 
   \end{array} \right) \sim N \left( 0, \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
              \Sigma_{vv} & 0 \\
              0 & \Sigma_{ww} 
   \end{array} \right] \right)
\end{equation}

where $\Phi_f(.)$ is a $p$ th-order polynomial on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\Phi_u(.)$ is a $q$ th-order polynomial on $\mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$. In order to have identification, we assume $\Lambda:= [I,\Lambda'_2]'$ and $\Phi_u (.)$ and $\Sigma_{ww}$ diagonal. 

\begin{equation} \label{73}
\widehat{y}_{t_q} = \alpha + \beta \widehat{f}_{t_q}
\end{equation}

\bibliographystyle{apa}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your `\widehat` command comes from which package?

Comment: all we know is you have a local incompatible definition somewhere. Impossible to say anything. Please make a small document and add it to your question  `begin{document}$\widehat{y}_{t_q}$\end{document}` preceded by whatever class and package commands are needed to show the bad output in your image.

Comment: Your MWE compiles just fine for me. Do you mind posting your `.log` file. Also, it might be a good idea to minimize the MWE even futher, for example that `\bibliographystyle` is probably not needed. Try making the smallest doc possible that still show the error (this is often how the rest of us debug such things)

Comment: Thank you so much @daleif, in the mean time Willie Wong has found where the problem was. But thanks anyway for the suggestions. Thank you all for all your fast replies and kind attention!

Answer (score 3):

The culprit is `breqn`. The `breqn` package is known to have incompatibilities with other packages that deal with the mathematics environments, which means most of the `ams*` packages. For example:

- [Why does adding \usepackage{breqn}, even if not used, cause LaTeX compile errors in some places?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119334/why-does-adding-usepackagebreqn-even-if-not-used-cause-latex-compile-errors)
- [Error with \widetilde](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321721/error-with-widetilde)

The simple solution is to load `breqn` **after** loading any of the AMS packages. For example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{70}
\left( \begin{array}{c}
              v_{t_m} \\
              u_{t_m} 
   \end{array} \right) \sim N \left( 0, \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
              \Sigma_{vv} & 0 \\
              0 & \Sigma_{ww} 
   \end{array} \right] \right)
\end{equation}

where $\Phi_f(.)$ is a $p$ th-order polynomial on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\Phi_u(.)$ is a $q$ th-order polynomial on $\mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$. In order to have identification, we assume $\Lambda:= [I,\Lambda'_2]'$ and $\Phi_u (.)$ and $\Sigma_{ww}$ diagonal. 

\begin{equation} \label{73}
\widehat{y}_{t_q} = \alpha + \beta \widehat{f}_{t_q}
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

compiles without the duplication of `y`. But if you move `\usepackage{breqn}` before `\usepackage{amsfonts}` as you do in your example, you get the problem you showed in your post.

Comment: Thank you so much @Willie Wong! That was exactly the problem! Now it works just fine, even for the whole code. Thanks a lot for your help!