# Incompatibility with MTPro Lite and breqn packages

Tags: breqn, mtpro

There is an incompatibility with the MTPro Lite and breqn packages that breaks the \implies symbol definition.

At my sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[lite,subscriptcorrection,slantedGreek,nofontinfo]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fixmath}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

Let $x\implies y$. Can you see the problem?

\end{document}
```

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: probably not a solution or a duplicate, but it may explain some things: [amsmath and amsfonts incompatibility issues](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/325264/579).  `breqn` has a lot of compatibility issues.

Comment: Well, `\implies` does not appear in the LaTeX manual.

Comment: On the other hand, also `\Longrightarrow` breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be in that `mtpro2` uses a different code for `\Relbar` than the standard one.

Here's a fix, but I don't know if it breaks something else.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \edef\Relbar{\mathord{\mathchar\the\numexpr\Relbar-"3000}}%
}

\begin{document}

$a \Longrightarrow b \Longleftarrow c$

$a \implies b \impliedby c$

\end{document}
```

[image]